# PHP upgrade fails due to libiconv.2.dylib. Should I symlink?

Tags: macports, dylib, php-5.6, otool, libiconv

I am trying to upgrade to PHP 5.6 from PHP 5.5. Then I receive the following error on `curl` install:

```
Executing post-install script /tmp/5.6-10.10-frontenddev-post-install
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/grep
  Reason: Incompatible library version: grep requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
Restarting Apache
```

I have:

1. No environment variables set for dylib
2. `otool -L /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib` returns: `/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)`
3. `port installed` returns `libiconv @1.14_0 (active)`, the latest version.

It looks like:

`otool -DL /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib`

returns:

```
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

So the system version is being accessed by PHP install. How can I make it point to the local lib version?

Trying `sudo port -n upgrade --force libiconv` for now..

Comment: How did you check whether you had any `DLYD_*` variables set? If you're on El Capitan, `/usr/bin/env` and `/usr/bin/printenv` now longer show those variables due to System Integrity Protection. Try `(set -o posix; set) | grep DYLD` in a shell instead. Additionally, it is possible the the post-install script sets `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib`, which would explain this behavior.

Comment: It specifically says `Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib` so it's not looking at the system version. If this problem is still outstanding, what does the post-install script look like? If not, go ahead and delete or self-answer the question.